# What is the process within the Catholic Church to get a clarification on Church teaching?

Tags: catholicism, papal-magisterium

From this [Meta discussion](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4150/how-is-the-site-equipped-to-reveal-the-correct-answer), the post presented the case that on *C.SE*, one may find irreconcilable answers to the question *What is the Catholic Church's position on the scientific theory of evolution?*

The question is what is the process within the Catholic Church which will enable a person to get a clarification on Church teaching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write to the [Congregation for the Doctrine of the Faith (CDF)](http://www.vatican.va/roman_curia/congregations/cfaith/index.htm). That commission addresses doctrinal questions.

---

From the [profile page of Congregation for the Doctrine of the Faith](http://www.vatican.va/roman_curia//congregations/cfaith/documents/rc_con_cfaith_pro_14071997_en.html)

> E-mail: cdf@cfaith.va

---

For an example, which is relevant to the current discussions in the Church, please see [this CDF *October 22, 2014* response](http://rorate-caeli.blogspot.com/2014/11/four-days-after-synod-closed-cdf.html?m=1) to the Question of a French Priest: *"Can a confessor grant absolution to a penitent who, having been religiously married, has contracted a second union following divorce?"*

Comment: @FMS: Nice edits; I hadn't heard of the recent CDF answer, either. thanks